# Find a basis of $W^{\perp}$ with $W = 2x_{1}+3x_{2}+x_{3}-2x_{4}$

Tags: linear-algebra

I need to find an orthogonal basis -$W^{\perp}$- for $W = 2x_{1}+3x_{2}+x_{3}-2x_{4}$ in $\mathbb{R^{4}}$.

For a problem like this, what I need to do is:

1. Define four-dimensional vectors (How many of them?)
2. Calculate the null space for that vector(s).

Is that correct? If not, what do I need to do to solve this problem?

Comment: Your definition of $W$ looks wrong. What are the $x_i$ and why should $W$ be their sum?

Comment: Shouldn't that sum be equalled to zero? Otherwise there is no subspace here at all...

Answer (score 2):

Assuming 
$$
W = \{ (x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4) \mid (2,3,1,-2) \cdot (x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4) = 0 \}
$$
then $W$ consists of all vectors orthogonal to $n = (2,3,1,-2)$ in other words $W^\perp = \{ \alpha n \mid \alpha \in \mathbb{R} \}$ and its base is $\{ n \}$.